# HBase schema file for a product

Tags: java, hbase, nosql

We have been using HBase for one of our products. We have many tables, each with different column families and their own configurations related to regions, time to live etc..

Now I want to bundle all the details into an installer program, which upon running will generate all the tables as required. Is there a well known way to do that?

All am looking forward to is something similar to what we write in RDBMS tables schema file (like .sql files etc). Or we have to write a program to do the same manually in Java?

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling HBase "schema" is a common problem for products using HBase. Because of the complexities involved, packaging `.sql` files with  `create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 3}` statements might be **unreliable** and **error prone**.

The suggested way is using the [HBaseAdmin](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html) class. You can do as follows:

1. Within your code, create an 'Installer' class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method that uses [createTable](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#createTable(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor)) (and other methods) to create the "schema" required
2. Call above class as an installation step.
   e.g. `java -cp /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hbase/conf:<your-product>.jar namespace.Installer`